# Twitter-bootstrap - How to distribute content using "span" within a well if the well is already in it's own span?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

I created a span on the right side of the page that contains a well. Within that well I'm trying to align many lines of images and text using multiple div class="span__" commands. Everything gets placed properly, however it's pushed outside of the well by the first  within the well.

```
<!-- The “well” below is on the right side of the page (other content span=3 is on the left of it) -->
```

### Heading

*supporting text*

```
    <!-- Above content is all correctly contained in the well, but I want the content below in the well too, but also want to distribute several lines horizontally. Using the “span=” below, within the “span8 offset0” opened above does distribute the content properly from a horizontal standpoint, but it gets removed from the well. Is there a way, such as a “sub-span” to place content horizontally while still INSIDE the well? Please note, as you can see from the various span= entries below, I’m not looking to just center them.  -->


    <div class="span3 offset2">
    <img src="assets/img/vote211x58.png" alt="vote" width="211" height="58" hspace="7">
    </div>
```

Button left

```
   <div class="span2 offset0">
     <p></p><a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">Button middle</a>
     </div>

    <div class="span2 offset0">
      <p><a class="btn btn-xlarge" href="#">Button right</a></p>
    </div>
    <!--end line of buttons -->


   <!-- start new line, want all contained in the well, but distributed horizontally -->
    <div class="span2 offset1">
       <p><img src="assets/img/why-green.png" alt="why green" width="32" height="45" hspace="18"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="span1">
    <!--  <a class="btn small" href="#">view stats</a> -->
       <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="span2 offset1">
      <p><img src="assets/img/why-red.png" alt="why red" width="32" height="45" hspace="16"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- end last line of content I want included in the well -->

    </div>  <!-- closes the well -->
    </div>  <!-- closes the span=8 containing the well  -->


    </div>  <!-- closes the row containing the left span=3 content + the span=8 content holding the well.  THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP! -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem and you seem to be missing some code, can you create a jsFiddle to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution, but may work in some situations:

create a new well (e.g. ".well-new") in CSS (so it doesn't screw-up other uses of "well" throughout your site) and give it much larger bottom padding (padding: 19px 19px **180px** 19px;) and a correspondingly large negative margin-bottom (I used -168px;) - the effect is the bottom of the well extends much lower, incorporating the content below to well, into it.

I'm not sure how this affects renderings on mobile devices.

Better answers welcome!